# low volume in ALSA sound

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I am running linux kernel 4.4.0 with Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS with ALSA for sound. This distribution comes with `pulseaudio` by default but I uninstalled it to run all the sounds directly with ALSA.

When `pulseaudio` was installed the sound worked fine as I was able to hear system sounds well. But after uninstalling `pulseaudio` I can not hear any sounds.

The sound is actually generated but the volume is so low that you can't hear anything.

I set the volume to MAX 100% for all the playback for this sound card in `alsamixer` but that does not help.

any idea what could be wrong here ?

the output of `cat /proc/asound/cards` is:

```
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                  HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7430000 irq 33
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                  HDA NVidia at 0xf3080000 irq 17
 2 [amplifier      ]: USB-Audio - 4.1 amplifier
                  4.1 amplifier at usb-0000:00:14.0-5, full speed
```

My sound is the `4.1 Amplifier` device, which is `card 2`

The amplifier section in `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state` is :

```
state.amplifier {
    control.1 {
            iface PCM
            name 'Playback Channel Map'
            value.0 0
            value.1 0
            value.2 0
            value.3 0
            value.4 0
            value.5 0
            value.6 0
            value.7 0
            comment {
                    access read
                    type INTEGER
                    count 8
                    range '0 - 36'
            }
    }
    control.2 {
            iface PCM
            name 'Capture Channel Map'
            value.0 0
            value.1 0
            comment {
                    access read
                    type INTEGER
                    count 2
                    range '0 - 36'
            }
    }
    control.3 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Mic Playback Switch'
            value false
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type BOOLEAN
                    count 1
            }
    }
    control.4 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Mic Playback Volume'
            value.0 6144
            value.1 6144
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type INTEGER
                    count 2
                    range '0 - 8065'
                    dbmin -2400
                    dbmax 750
                    dbvalue.0 -1
                    dbvalue.1 -1
            }
    }
    control.5 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Line Playback Switch'
            value false
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type BOOLEAN
                    count 1
            }
    }
    control.6 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Line Playback Volume'
            value.0 6144
            value.1 6144
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type INTEGER
                    count 2
                    range '0 - 8065'
                    dbmin -2400
                    dbmax 750
                    dbvalue.0 -1
                    dbvalue.1 -1
            }
    }
    control.7 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Speaker Playback Switch'
            value true
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type BOOLEAN
                    count 1
            }
    }
    control.8 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Speaker Playback Volume'
            value.0 122
            value.1 122
            value.2 196
            value.3 196
            value.4 196
            value.5 196
            value.6 196
            value.7 196
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type INTEGER
                    count 8
                    range '0 - 197'
                    dbmin -3693
                    dbmax 0
                    dbvalue.0 -1406
                    dbvalue.1 -1406
                    dbvalue.2 -19
                    dbvalue.3 -19
                    dbvalue.4 -19
                    dbvalue.5 -19
                    dbvalue.6 -19
                    dbvalue.7 -19
            }
    }
    control.9 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Mic Capture Switch'
            value true
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type BOOLEAN
                    count 1
            }
    }
    control.10 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Mic Capture Volume'
            value.0 4096
            value.1 4096
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type INTEGER
                    count 2
                    range '0 - 6928'
                    dbmin -1600
                    dbmax 1106
                    dbvalue.0 -1
                    dbvalue.1 -1
            }
    }
    control.11 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Line Capture Switch'
            value true
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type BOOLEAN
                    count 1
            }
    }
    control.12 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'Line Capture Volume'
            value.0 4096
            value.1 4096
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type INTEGER
                    count 2
                    range '0 - 6928'
                    dbmin -1600
                    dbmax 1106
                    dbvalue.0 -1
                    dbvalue.1 -1
            }
    }
    control.13 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'IEC958 In Capture Switch'
            value true
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type BOOLEAN
                    count 1
            }
    }
    control.14 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'PCM Capture Switch'
            value true
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type BOOLEAN
                    count 1
            }
    }
    control.15 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'PCM Capture Volume'
            value.0 4096
            value.1 4096
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type INTEGER
                    count 2
                    range '0 - 6928'
                    dbmin -1600
                    dbmax 1106
                    dbvalue.0 -1
                    dbvalue.1 -1
            }
    }
    control.16 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'PCM Capture Source'
            value Mic
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type ENUMERATED
                    count 1
                    item.0 Mic
                    item.1 Line
                    item.2 'IEC958 In'
                    item.3 Mixer
            }
    }
}
```

I did set the volume for all the playback channels to MAX in `alsamixer` but that does not work. The volume is still very very low.